# how to set the css+html file in the iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

how to set the css+html file in the iphone

```
UIWebView   * webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,458)];
webView.delegate=self;
[self.view addSubview:webView];

NSString *sPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:sPath];
NSString *htmlContant = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:sPath];
htmlContant = [htmlContant stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"menu.css"];
  NSString *content = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.getSelection().toString()"];
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:htmlContant,content] baseURL:targetURL];
```

Comment: how to pick the css file in the iphone

Comment: What do you mean by "pick the CSS file"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *htmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"demo" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSURL *Url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];
[WebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:Url];
```

And Don't forget to link the css in html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Sample.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

*Sample.html*

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

*style.css*

```
body
{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

*objective -c code:*

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sample" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:nil];

    NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlFile];

[WebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**. Your base url looks incorrect. because it contains index.html in your `targetURL`. Base path must be without any file names.

**Second**. You are trying to append css file name in your html content.

Why you are loading css file programatically if you have already stored in application bundle. You can simply write the following line in your html file to load external css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="menu.css">
```

**Tip:** Whenever you have such problems. You can set the break points on the suspected lines and try to print those variable values in console using `PO` command.

Reference Link : http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/windows-views/uiwebview-revisited